# How do I define a Gorenstein curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How can I define a Gorestein curve with the following definition:

For each $\lambda\in\Omega_{k(C)/k}$, define $\omega_{\lambda}\in {\rm Frac}(C)$, such that for all $P\in C$ the stalk $\omega_{\lambda,P}$ is the greatest between the $\mathcal{O}_P$-fractional ideals $F$ in $k(C)$ such that $\sum_{\overline{P}|P}{\rm{Res}}_{\overline{P}}(f\lambda)=0$ for all $f\in F$. Besides, we have $\omega_C\cong\omega_{\lambda}$ for all $\lambda\in\Omega_{k(C)/k}$.